# For what values of $a$ will the lines $ay+3x=4$ and $2y+4x=3$ have no intersection points?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Multiple choice question:

> For what values of $a$ will the lines $ay+3x=4$ and $2y+4x=3$ have no intersection points?
>
> - A)  2
> - B) 1.5
> - C) 8/3
> - D) -0.5
> - E) -2
>
>   ---

I tried rearranging them into $y=mx+b$ form and solve, but I will end up with a literal answer like this

$$a=\frac{(4-3x)}{y}$$

How do you work this out? I think you need to make the gradient the same but how do you do that?

Comment: When the slopes are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the slopes (or gradients) of the lines are the same, as @DavidG.Stork puts it, then the lines will be parallel and never meet. Remember that the Cartesian Plane is *infinitely* long and wide, so if the lines are not parallel, they will eventually meet and thus intersect. Therefore, the lines *must* be parallel, and so the slopes must also be equal to each other. In both the equations, we have $$y = -\frac{3}{a}x + \frac{4}{a}\,\text{ and }\,y = -2x + \frac{3}{2}$$ so if the slopes are the same, we have $-2 = -\dfrac{3}{a}$ and therefore, the negatives cancel out and $a = \dfrac{3}{2}$. We conclude by stating that the correct answer is $B)$.

This is because $m$ represents the slope in the linear equation, $y = mx + b$.

Answer (score 7):

Transforming the two to the form $y=mx+b$ we get the two lines
$$
y=-\frac 3ax+\frac4a\\
y=-\frac42x+\frac32
$$
If the lines don't intersect, they *must have the same slope*. So set the two slopes equal, and solve for $a$.

After we've found our $a$, we must remember to check that there are indeed no solutions, rather than infinitely many. We do this by inserting the value for $a$ that we found, solve the system of equations the regular way, and make sure that we get something like $0=1$ at the end instead of, say, $4=4$. Alternatively, insert that value of $a$ into our $y=mx+b$ form equations above and confirm that we get lines with different constant term.

Answer (score 6):

Pedestrian approach:

Subtract $3$× second equation from from $4$×first equation to eliminate $x:$

$4ay-6y= 7;$

$2y(2a- 3) =7;$

$\rightarrow :$

$2a-3 \not =0$ (why?).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the system

- $ay+3x=4\implies 4ay+12x=16$
- $2y+4x=3\implies 6y+12x=9$

then if $a=\frac32$ LHS become equals but RHS are different thus the system has no solution and we don't have intersection points.

Answer (score 4):

They will have no intersection points when and only when the lines are distinct parallel lines. Since the second line is $2y+4x=3$, the lines will be parallel when the first line is $\lambda\times(2y+4x)=\alpha$, for some numbers $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ with $\lambda\neq0$. But the first line is $ay+3x=4$ and therefore $\lambda$ can only be $\frac32$ and in this case the lines are indeed distinct lines.

Answer (score 3):

If the lines do not intersect it means that they are parallel and their slope must be equal. 
That is:

m1 = m2.
Where m1 =`-coff. of x of first eq./coff. Of y of first eq.

& 
m2= - coff. of x of second eq./ coff. of y of second eq.

i.e.,

-a/3 = -2/4 
 Solving this we get

a = 3/2.

Answer (score 2):

The system is equivalent to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&a\\
4&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Let $A$ be the $2\times 2$ matrix above. The lines don't intersect iff $(4,
3)^T$ is not in the span of the columns of $A$. The lines don't intersect iff the columns are linearly dependent (as $(4,3)^T\notin\text{span} \{(3,4)^T$}. Thus the lines don't intersect iff
$$
\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ whence $\lambda a=3$ i.e. $a=3/2$.

Comment: Could you possibly make things more complicated?

Comment: I like how his approach is different though, but I guess it is unsuitable...